# How to log user in programatically with Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm testing my dashboard controller, which requires a user to login in order to access. Below is my code

require 'test_helper'

```
class DashboardControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

 test "should redirect if not logged in" do
   get :index
   assert_response 302
 end

 test "should get index if logged in" do

   user = User.create(:username => "trivektor", :password => "abcd", :email =>   "trivektor@gmail.com", :first_name => "Tri", :last_name => "Vuong", :active => true)

   user_session = UserSession.create(:email => "trivektor@gmail.com", :password => "abcd")

   # get :index
   # assert_response 200
 end
end
```

However, I always get this error

Authlogic::Session::Activation::NotActivatedError: You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating objects

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate authlogic before creating a new UserSession, just create a new test file and add this:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  setup :activate_authlogic
end
```